# Matplotlib столбчатая диаграмма (bar)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я построила столбачатую диаграмму:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.bar(data.index, data)
```

Каким образом изменить цвет одного столбца, имеющего наибольшее значение?

Comment: используйте параметр colors в ax.bar.  colors - список цветов по количеству столбцов.  Если приведете датасет, можно будет сделать конкретный пример.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобралась. Ваш ответ не совсем про то что мне надо было - использование списка цветов закрашивает все столбцы, а не конкретный - максимальный или минимальный.

Comment: Значит вы не до конца разобрались. Вы можете генерировать список цветов в зависимости от того, какой столбец максимальный/минимальный.